# Gravity Forms columns side by side

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, gravity-forms-plugin

In case you are wondering how to have side by side columns in Wordpress gravity forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is taken from [here](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_content) and [here](http://www.jordancrown.com/multi-column-gravity-forms/), and simplified.

First go to Form Settings and add class `two-column` to Form Layout.

Then go ahead and add a section break in the beginning of your Gravity Form items.
Add another section break to where ever you want your form to split.
Then add class `gform_column` to both section break's from Advanced tab.

After this go to your `functions.php` and paste the following (hook) :

```
function gform_column_splits($content, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id) {
if(!is_admin()) { // only perform on the front end
    if($field['type'] == 'section') {
        $form = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta($form_id, true);

        // check for the presence of multi-column form classes
        $form_class = explode(' ', $form['cssClass']);
        $form_class_matches = array_intersect($form_class, array('two-column', 'three-column'));

        // check for the presence of section break column classes
        $field_class = explode(' ', $field['cssClass']);
        $field_class_matches = array_intersect($field_class, array('gform_column'));

        // if field is a column break in a multi-column form, perform the list split
        if(!empty($form_class_matches) && !empty($field_class_matches)) { // make sure to target only multi-column forms

            // retrieve the form's field list classes for consistency
            $form = RGFormsModel::add_default_properties($form);
            $description_class = rgar($form, 'descriptionPlacement') == 'above' ? 'description_above' : 'description_below';

            // close current field's li and ul and begin a new list with the same form field list classes
            return '</li></ul><ul class="gform_fields '.$form['labelPlacement'].' '.$description_class.' '.$field['cssClass'].'"><li class="gfield gsection empty">';

        }
    }
}

return $content;
}

add_filter('gform_field_content', 'gform_column_splits', 100, 5);
```

This will close the `ul` and open a new one, which can be style to be next to each other.

Now just add the following to your styles

```
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields {
display: none;
}
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_column li.gsection:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

And that should do the magic.

Comment: Update: Version 2.6.8

Change the ul li tags to div in return format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Gravity Forms 1.5 or newer you can just use "Ready Classes".

For 2 Columns: Simply create two fields you want side by side and add the Custom CSS class gf_left_half to the first field and gf_right_half to the second one.

For 3 Columns: Use classes gf_left_third, gf_middle_third, and gf_right_third for the fields.

Inline fields: Use gf_inline for each field.

For other classes including list-item columns check out the [Gravity Forms CSS Ready Classes Documentation](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/css-ready-classes/).

Comment: Any ideas if you wanted to have 3 columns. 1) Email 2) Password (first) 3) Password (repeat)

Answer (score 0):

fantastic solution above..  Use this to make your form responsive:

```
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields {
    display: none;
}

.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_column li.gsection:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```